Why won't program run if not located at C:\program files after installing dual boot?
Few months ago, I installed Ubuntu 22 on my laptop as dual boot with Windows 10. All programs worked properly before I apply dual boot on my laptop. However since I installed dual boot, I have an issue where apps that are not installed in C:\Program Files or C:\Program Files(x86) won't run at all on windows.
The issue only occurs on Windows. I've checked this issue by installing a small sized game (chess) on disk D:. It won't run at all, but after I move it to C:\Program Files, it run without any problem. I've tried another directories in C:, but only those 2 that able to run any program. And now my disk C: only has very limited free space and I hope I can install softwares at D:.
I have checked many forums but no one has explained similar problem. Maybe reinstalling both Windows and Ubuntu may solve the issue, but I want to look for another way to solve it.

I am confused. You said applications won’t run but you also said you moved this small application and it did run. So which is it?

One thing we can be sure of: It has nothing to do  with dual-booting.

it only runs when It's located on 'C:\Program Files' directory. Outside this directory, any apps can't run without any error message. I found this problem after install dual boot, so I thought there might be any correlation with it. I'm puzzled what cause this problem
